# How to take only the last values for zip in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have two observables, one can emit events very fast. I need to sync them, e.g. when observable1 emits, I take the last one from observable2 and do some stuff.
How I do it:

```
Observable<PairingState> pairingState = CoroutinesHelperKt.toObservable(mManager.getPairingStatusFlow())
            .filter(state -> state == PairingState.Paired);

Observable<...> added = mCallbackManager.getSomeObservable("...")
            .filter(participant -> !participant.participant.getId().equals(mUserManager.getUserId()));

mStateSubscription = Observable.zip(pairingState, added, (state, user) -> true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(MESSAGE_SEND_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(event -> {
                //do some stuff
            });
```

Question: how to take only the last one from observable2 ?

I'm trying to solve the problem when 2 emits 100 elements, and I have just one from observable1

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should use .combineLatest operator

Comment: @SpKiwi, yes, that's it, I forgot about this operator. Pls post as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose .combineLatest should be used. So it would be:

```
mStateSubscription = Observable.combineLatest(pairingState, added, (state, user) -> true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(MESSAGE_SEND_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(event -> {
                //do some stuff
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

While `combineLatest` might be what you need, you should also look at [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#withLatestFrom-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.BiFunction-).

- `combineLatest`: When observable 1 emits, use the latest value from observable 2.  When observable 2 emits, use the latest value from observable 1.
- `withLatestFrom`: When observable 1 emits, use the latest value from observable 2.  When observable 2 emits, only update internal state.